# How to get deathbycaptcha module in my python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, captcha

So I'm scrapping websites and I want to use deathbycaptcha services to solve captchas. I don't understand how to install deathbycaptcha module on my python so that I can import it in my script.

The website gives instructions and package to download for python, but I have no idea how to install it. 
http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/api

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install deathbycaptcha`

```
client = deathbycaptcha.SocketClient(username, password)
```

Then, you can use it as documented in API documentation. Worked for me.

The simplest of the solution to start with deathbycaptcha is start working in the directory where you have all the api code downloaded. Start by reading new_recaptcha_coordinates.py file. Put your username and password and run it.